# Changing the memory address instead of the value in a struct on C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

This is my program. (Sorry, the constants and names of structs and variables are in my language)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

/*CONSTANTES*/
#define MAX_CHAR 8
#define MAX_NOM_IMPR (20+1)
#define NUM_ELEM 10
#define MAX_IMPR 4
#define MAX_FICHEROS 6
#define ERROR_ARGC 0
#define ERROR_LONG 1
#define ERROR_COLALLENA 2
#define ERROR_NO_OPCION 3
#define ERROR_MAX_IMPR 4
#define ERROR_NOM_REP 5
#define ERROR_NO_IMP 6
#define ERROR_NO_IMP_REP 7
#define ERROR_LONG_IMPR 8

/*TIPOS DE DATOS*/
typedef char Telemento[MAX_CHAR+5];

typedef struct{
   Telemento arraycola[NUM_ELEM];
   int inicio;
   int final;
}TCola;

typedef char TNombreImpresora[MAX_NOM_IMPR];

typedef struct{
   TNombreImpresora nombreimpresora;
   int numerodeficherosencola;
   TCola colaImpresora;
}TImpresora;

typedef struct{
   TImpresora impresora;
   int ocupado;
}TCelda;

typedef TCelda Tlistaimpresora[MAX_IMPR];


int main(){
   Tlistaimpresora listaimpresora;

   listaimpresora[1].ocupado=1;
   printf("%s", listaimpresora[1].ocupado);
}
```

When I run it, it crashes and I figured out that: Instead of changing the value of `ocupado`, I changed the memory address and I don't know why. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which Data type you are used ?

Comment: you didn't show enough of the code. Add definition of Tlistawhatever

Comment: `printf("%s", listaimpresora[1].ocupado);` You're sending an `int` to a `printf` format that requires a null terminated string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not post the `Tlistaimpresora` structure details.

However, there are some common mistakes.

1. you have defined a single variable of type `Tlistaimpresora`, and you're accessing `listaimpresora[1]` ?
2. considered `Tlistaimpresora` is a typedef of `struct abc *`, you did not allocate memory for the variable.

---

EDIT:

well, after the full code, it looks your problem is here

```
printf("%s", listaimpresora[1].ocupado);
```

`listaimpresora[1].ocupado` is of type `int` and needs `%d` format specifier. `%s` specifier is used to print strings and expects a null-terminated string to print for.

Answer (score 2):

You are printing the integer variable in string format. So this is the reason for getting the segmentation fault. So make this into

```
printf("%d", listaimpresora[1].ocupado);
```

You will get the answer.